# pull the data from SAP BW system and process in Java

Tags: java, sap-bw

We have a requirement to develop an application that pulls the data from SAP BW system and display it on a Flex chart.

The Flex guy wants the data in the XML format. I am the middleWare guy who sits in between the SAP BW and the Flex. I need to pull the data from SAP BW system and feed the Flex components in XML.

**Question:** How do I pull the data from SAP BW system, process it and convert to XML?

Initial thoughts:

1. The SAP BW system generates a CSV file. Process that CSV file and generate the XML. Basically I am a Java guy, so I am thinking it as a JAVA WEB-SERVICE.

Any other thoughts, better approaches, please?

Thank You :)

Comment: whats your middleware platfrom like? how will your process be initiated and how will you intimate Flex of its output?

Answer (score 1):

The good folks at SAP have a generic web service for accessing BW data.

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/d8/3bfc3f8fc2c542e10000000a1550b0/content.htm

Please don't generate CSV files in BW, it's really bad karma ;]